# Dojo how to catch user's input of Dojo.FilteringSelect for onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am catching up an `onkeyup` event on dojo `filteringSelect` However seems

```
var userInput = dijit.byId('someId').attr("value");
```

Only return either "" or some value precisely equals to one of the options. So seems like the filteringSelect can only return the `<Select>` part of the dijit instead of value of the `<input type="text">` part, as regarding `onkeyup` event.

So what is the right procedure to catch user's current input of the FilteringSelect? BTW, current application is on Dojo 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you should probably try the `"displayedValue"` attribute:

```
var userInput = dijit.byId('someId').get("displayedValue");
```

If you ever need some information about what property you could use, I recommend reading the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect#displayedValue) (for the dijit library it is usually well documented).